# Why isn't port mapping working on my Docker container in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: docker, nginx

Port mapping on docker is not working on ubuntu 20.04 dedicated server.

I started a nginx container:

```
docker run -d --name some-nginx -p 3000:80 nginx
```

The docker ps command says the container is working fine:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                   NAMES
7f02f38541ab   nginx     "/docker-entrypoint.…"   59 minutes ago   Up 59 minutes   0.0.0.0:3000->80/tcp, :::3000->80/tcp   some-nginx
```

I expect to recieve the nginx default page but instead I recieve nothing:

```
curl http://localhost:3000
```

I tried the command in the container and it worked fine.

```
docker exec -it some-nginx bash
```

```
curl http://localhost:80
```

I recieved:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
html { color-scheme: light dark; }
body { width: 35em; margin: 0 auto;
font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I started on a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04 and installed docker via this guide:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-20-04

In the past I installed docker on a shared VPS (Ubuntu 20.04), then port mapping worked fine.

Does anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: When you say `i receive nothing`, what is the actual http response?

Comment: The request basically times out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an issue with iptables...

Not sure if this is the best solution but I edited the file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`. I changed the line that starts with `ExecStart` to this:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --iptables=false -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

Then ran: `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and `sudo systemctl restart docker`. After that port mapping worked again.

Credits to **tobetter** (https://forum.odroid.com/viewtopic.php?p=349424#p349424) for this solution.